# Why am I getting a traceback saying "Invalid argument" after entering the url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, traceback

Entered file name: `http://www.dr-chuck.com`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sree\Desktop\py4e\crawl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
  File "C:\Users\Sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email
  File "C:\Users\Sree\Desktop\py4e\email.py", line 2, in <module>
    fh = open(fname)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://www.dr-chuck.com'
```

Any url I enter is being ruled as an invalid argument! Please help!

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter: ') 
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

Comment: Give us the complete, verbatim error message please.

Comment: @deceze Not able to add the error message...the question is not being reviewed

Comment: Don't use urllib. Use requests. `page = requests.get(url) soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Apparently you have a file `email.py` in your environment which gets imported here which is triggering the actual error. Rename that file to something else so it doesn't conflict with Python's builtin `email` module.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! It worked!